# Windows 7 - Unable to connect to wireless or wired Internet

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

I was deleting some files from the program files folder ( now I'm thinking why) and in a little while I notice my chrome browser just closed. Later I note that my laptop is not connecting to the wifi signals and shortly I was not able to see any wireless connections available as well as unable to connect to internet via lan.

When I go into the network connections, I don't see anything there, no wireless connections and the other local area connection thing.

What should I do? I don't have any backup CDs as well. Does anyone know what happened here and how to fix it? If you need any information let me know and I'll provide.

Thank you.

**Update**

Thank you all for your help. With the help of this post I was able to successfully download and reinstall windows and keep all my data. You guys are amazing, really great thing you all are doing here!

As to why I did such a thing, I am not sure, I think I was really drowsy after a very long day and since windows is my backup computer (I usually use mac) and it had been ages since I last used it I had forgotten how easily it lets you fiddle with the setup essential files. Either way I did poke the bear in a cave where I was not suppose to be in.

Comment: 1) Why on earth you were messing with files/folders you didn't understand.... 2) Have you tried `System Restore` 3) Have you tried `sfc /scannow` 4) Have you tried to do a Windows repair install...?

Comment: SFC.EXE /scannow like @BigChris suggests is the first thing to try.

Comment: @BigChris I know but I guess I learned the hard way :( Was a very long day and I was really drowsy I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, as BigChris mentions, do not mess with files you dont understand!

However, if your issue is occures because you corrupted essential files, there are several steps to take.

First of all, check your trashfolder. The files might still be there. **Restore any date thats present in the trashfolder**. Restart your pc, maybe it was that easy, however, this is unlikely.

Next try: **reinstall software that might be corrupted**. 
In your case, reinstall the mainboard drivers, as well as the network controller drivers.

If this did not fix the problem, you've probably destroyed some critical stuff. Fixing this without reinstall the OS is not trivial and is not in the scope of SE.

**Save your data and reinstall the OS**
Copy the files (only the files, no installed software) to one of these:

- external harddrive
- internal harddrive or partition which is not the one where your OS is installed.
- any other external device which is capable storing your data.

Go to microsoft.com download section and download the OS you are using (e.g. win7 64bit) You might have to use another computer, due yours seems not to be capable of this anymore.

[Install](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool) the OS.iso to an Flashdrive, check the link for guidance.

This flashdrive now is bootable and can be used in the same way as you know it from the install CD/DVD.

Boot from that flashdrive and simply reinstall the operation system.

Most of the time, the windows installer will copy your old windows folder into windows.old and doesn't touch your private data.
However, in some cases this goes wrong, so you should save your data anyways.

**If this still did not fix your problem:**

Boot from the stick again.
At the point you are asked for the partition where windows should be installed to, you have to format the partition with the currently installed windows. After that step, you wont have access to your data again, unless you're a data security guy in which case you shouldn't have to ask this.

Reinstall windows again.

You now have a totaly fresh installed windows, with no drivers, no private data, no third party software.
Install the drivers, get your data back, reinstall the programms you use.

If this still didn't fix the problem, it has nothing to do with the deleten files.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed guidance! I was able to successfully reinstall the windows and have all my data intact (feeling relieved). Reallly appreciate the support!!